# Keras doesn't fit linear function if more than 18 values provided

Tags: tensorflow2.0, tf.keras

I'm pretty new with Tensorflow and Keras. I was working through a simple example and found something strange that is puzzling me.

This is the function used for generate and train the model. It takes n as a parameter and generates y values as a simple line: y=50+50x using n examples (0,1,2,...,n-1)

```py
def real_value(rooms):
    return 50+50*rooms

def get_model(n):
    global xs, ys
    
    model = keras.Sequential([keras.layers.Dense(units = 1, input_shape = [1], use_bias=True)])
    model.compile(optimizer = 'sgd', loss = 'mean_squared_error')

    xs = np.arange(0,n, dtype=float)
    ys = np.array(list(map(real_value,xs)), dtype=float)

    print("fitting...")
    model.fit(xs, ys, epochs=5000, verbose=0)
    
    return model
```

If I call it with values between 2 and 18 all goes ok (first column is X, second column is Y, third column is predicted value):

```py
model = get_model(15)
list(zip(xs, ys, model.predict(xs)[:,0]))

[(0.0, 50.0, 49.99964),
 (1.0, 100.0, 99.99968),
 (2.0, 150.0, 149.99973),
 ...
 (12.0, 650.0, 650.0001),
 (13.0, 700.0, 700.0001),
 (14.0, 750.0, 750.0002)]
```

But as soon as I use more than 18 items to train the model, it returns NaN:

```py
model = get_model(19)
list(zip(xs, ys, model.predict(xs)[:,0]))

[(0.0, 50.0, nan),
 (1.0, 100.0, nan),
 (2.0, 150.0, nan),
 (3.0, 200.0, nan),
 ...
 (16.0, 850.0, nan),
 (17.0, 900.0, nan),
 (18.0, 950.0, nan)]
```

Don't have no idea why it happens. Any clue?

Library versions:

- tensorflow: 2.2.0
- numpy: 1.19.0
- tf.keras: 2.3.0-tf

Comment: It seem it has to be with Exploding Gradients:
https://machinelearningmastery.com/how-to-avoid-exploding-gradients-in-neural-networks-with-gradient-clipping/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seem it has to be with Exploding Gradients, as I said in the previous comment. Just changing the optimizer solves it:

```py
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import SGD


def get_model(n):
    ...
    opt = SGD(clipnorm=3000.0, clipvalue=5)
    model.compile(optimizer = opt, loss = 'mean_squared_error')
    ...
```